# Using template API, is there a way to get block content without rendering it?

Tags: django, django-templates

Suppose my template file is:

```
... {% block block1 %}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{variable}} adipiscing {% endblock %} ...
```

Using template API, I want to capture content of block "block1" without rendering the content:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {{variable}} adipiscing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it as follows:

```
from django.template.loaders import app_directories
loader = app_directories.Loader()
src = loader.load_template_source('app/index.html', ['templates',])
```

The `['templates',]` parameter is needed because it only seaches "templates" folders within apps, not a main "templates" folder in the root of your project.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I want. What I want is, using template API, "parse" a file template to extract only content for a specific block ( without rendering ).

Comment: I think this is all you have... you can access the blocks that have been found, but these are only stored after they have gone through Django's lexer and parser: the raw template data is then no longer available. So this is the closest you can get to that. This means that you'll have to parse the template yourself, but I'll admit that this isn't really using the API anymore: you could just load the file from disk and parse it then. But again, as far as I know, this is the closest you can get.

Comment: Ok Thank you. I wondered if that was possible with the API. But since it is not possible, I will parse the file myself.